# Content disappears while using UseNavigate Hook in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I am very new to React Js. I want to move from the App Page to the Contact page using react. I tried using the latest useNavigate feature of React . But as soon as I use that hook all the content on my page disappears. I have used the format mentioned in the documentation .
Here is my Code:-

App.Js

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
const navigate = useNavigate();

const goToContact = () => {
navigate('/Contact');
};

  return (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <button onClick={()=>goToContact()}>Contact</button>
  </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Contact.js

```
const Contact = () => {
    return ( 
        <div>
            <h1>Contact</h1>
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Contact;
```

[image]

**The file structure**

[image]

**The Output**

Comment: Did you [declare the routing](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: @keikai Thats for the older versions right?.

Comment: I don't see where you render `Contact` or a route that `App` can navigate to. Please include all relevant code in your post as a [mcve]. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @DrewReese I have included the code for Contact.js and the have shown the file directory where it is present

Comment: That doesn't answer my clarifying questions though. We need to see *where* and *how* `Contact` is rendered and *where* and *how* the `"/Contact"` route is rendered. The project's file directory organization is mostly irrelevant in terms of what a React app is rendering to the DOM. Is this related to, or a duplicate of, your previous [question](/q/74758037/8690857)? It doesn't seem too awfully different.

Comment: @DrewReese I didnt understand what more code should I include . I asked the similar question cuz i didnt get the answer .

Comment: I'm guessing at this point that you've not fully grasped what purpose the `react-router-dom` package serves and how to use it. Have you gone through the [Getting Started](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview) and [Main Concepts](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts) documentation to help get you started? I don't think you got a valuable answer to your other question since it too asked for a [mcve] that is yet to be provided.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create the `onClick` handler as a callback and mention the route in a browser router element so the click gets where to go. To simply navigate would not do that
e.g:

```
 <button onClick={goToContact}>Contact</button>
```

And for router use this:

```
<Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
  <Route path="/Contact" element={<Contact/>} />
</Routes>
```

`Routes` and `Route` are available in react-router-dom v6.

Router needs to be accessed in `App.js`.

Comment: `onClick={goToContact}` is *still* a callback, so it's unclear what you are saying is an issue, if there is one. `onClick={()=>goToContact()}` is functionally equivalent, though more verbose... it's still completely valid syntax.

Comment: I want to Navigate using buttons . So i used it.

Answer (score 0):

The router will not make any connection between the `Contact` component and the route `'/Contact'` on its own. You need to set up your routes to tell the router what it should render for each path. You can do this in App.js for example:

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Contact from './Contact'

const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const goToContact = () => {
    navigate('/Contact');
  };

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={(
        <div>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
          <button onClick={()=>goToContact()}>Contact</button>
        </div>
      )} />
      <Route path="/Contact" element={<Contact/>} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Note that I have moved the content into the `"/"` path, otherwise you would have that render next to the Contact page. You can set up any content that is repeated on each page (such as navigation) around the `<Routes>` element.